# Components of Mind According to Hindu Scriptures?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mind

The Mind is known in Vedas and another scriptures as Manas. Manas is not the same as Mind in modern science?

"when a man sits down to meditate thoughts rush up by dozens. The mind is only a bundle of thoughts" I found this statement and I haven't find the components of Mind details.

Any mentions in vedas or scriptures views?

Comment: Well Mind is a component of AntahKarana (Manas, Buddhi, Ahamkaara, Chitta = AntahKarana)

Comment: Component of Mind are illusions.Components of Consciousness are real.